# How to edit the title appearing on the mobile version of google results page?

Tags: wordpress, google-search

Its a bit of a SEO question. If you search something on Google on a mobile device you see something like this:

[image]

How do you edit or change the word inside the red circle? I thought it reflected what you have inside the title meta tag but it doesnt seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below `meta` tags in the header.php file (Appearance -> Theme File Editor -> Header.php)

**Note:** You can also access and edit the header.php file from wp-content/themes/{YOUR_THEME}/header.php via FTP/SSH

`og:title` is responsible for title shown in Google search results. For more details check out this link https://ogp.me/

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="Your Image URL" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description " />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website, Inc." />
</head>
```

Alternate Method : you can use [Meta Tag Manager](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/add-meta-tags-to-wordpress) to edit meta tag via plugin

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Yoast plugin for any SEO related questions for Wordpress:

https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/

I am pretty sure that you will be able to change the text in red circle with this plugin.

Comment: I have that plugin but it doesnt seem to change the text where is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` tag (which is not a `<meta>` tag) populates the heading text in blue or purple, below the two renderings of the URL. Not sure why Google on mobile renders the URL twice (once without the scheme), but it looks the same on my own sites.

[[image: screenshot]]

Comment: For some reason it will display it different on my site and many others. For example I have my site name inside the title tag like this `<title>My Blog</title>` but on the search page the URL will appear instead: `myblog.com`